# Limits of triple integration (prism)

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: 3D Prism]

Integrate $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2$ over the prism shown

My problem isn't the integration process but just to determine what the limits are.
$$\int_0^4 \int_{0}^{1-x} \int x^2 + y^2 dzdydx $$

I think those two limits may be correct but I don't know how to get the third, I understand how to find limits form a shape like a tetrahedron but a bit confused and my notes don't help me with this shape.

Comment: The upper limit of the second integral, $1-x$, looks wrong. The shape of the intersection of your volume with planes parallel to the $y,z$-axis doesn't depend on the plane's $x$-coordinate (so long as $x \in [0,4]$). Therefore the limits of the inner integrals shouldn't depend on $x$, either.

Comment: Think about this geometrically - integrating over $z,y$ computes the *area* of the intersection of your volume with a plane parallel to the $zy$-plane. But the area doesn't change as $x$ varies, precisely *because* the volume is a prism. Which is why the volume comes out as $Ah$, where $h$ is the height and $A$ the area of the base surface - the inner integrals always evaluate to $A$, independent from $x$, so the outer integral is just $\int_0^4 A \,dx = 4A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the plane that bounds that prism is given by

$$ z +y = 1 $$

Hence, your limits of integration goes from $0$ to $1 - y$.